# ValueError: could not convert string to float - kmeans (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, k-means, keyerror

I am trying to work with kmeans clusters trying to figure out if the infection rate of a certain number of patients is related to the number of procedures they had done in one surgery or if they were inpatient or a fresh admit from outside.

This is a snippet of my table: where I'm working with TerProNam which is the third procedure done within the surgery. Patient class is whether the patient was already in the hospital or just admitted for surgery. `PII_Dur` is how long the surgery lasted in minutes. `PI_7D` and `PI_14D` stand for whether the patient got an infection at 7 or 14 days after the surgery.

```
P_MRN   ProLS   PriProNam   SecProNam   TerProNam   P_Clas       PII_Dur PI_7D  PI_14D  ProRead
436772  1     CSection      BTL         5          Surgery Admit    214   0     1       0
436773  5     CSection      BTL         0          Inpatient        167   0     0       0
```

As you can see I have had to recode ProLS as procedure leading surgeon because of the same error that I get for TerProNam which says that it could not convert string to float.
This is the code I used with the ProLS and it worked:

```
#Converting ProLS values to float values 
ProLS = {'J. PENNY, MD': 1,'R. STRAW, DO': 2, 'K. BONES, DO': 3, 'W. MART, DO': 4, 'R. STRAW, DO': 5, 'HERNANDEZ, HERNAN, MD': 6, 'ESCAMILLA, EMILIO, MD': 7, 'DERICK, ERICK, DO': 8, 'BONE, MARK, DO': 9, 'PALLIATIVE, JACOB, MD': 10, 'ELLISHA, JOHN, MD': 11, 'SMITH, KELLY, MD': 12, 'WATCH, LILAH, DO': 13, 'THOMAS, BRANDY, DO': 14, 'MORE, ELIZABETH, DO': 15, 'KRUMB, TIM, MD': 16, 'COLE, FRED, MD': 17} 

  
cases.ProLS = [ProLS[item] for item in cases.ProLS] 
print(ProLS)
```

Now I tried the same thing with TerProNam:

```
#Converting TerProNam values to float values 
TerProNam = {'0': 0, 'Negative Pressure Wound Therapy; Abdomen': 1,'Including Injection Of Non-RadioactiveDye (In Addition To Primary Lymphadenectomy)': 2, 'Omentectomy; And Total Abdominal Hysterectomy': 3, 'Breast Reconstruction With Tissue Expander Insertion': 4, 'Axillary Lymphadenectomy; Complete': 5, 'Radical Dissection For Debulking Including Salpingo-Oophorectomy;': 6, 'Simple Mastectomy; Complete': 7} 

    
cases.TerProNam = [TerProNam[item] for item in cases.TerProNam] 

print(TerProNam)
```

It works but when I attempt to do the next code:

```
#Performing KMeans clustering assuming 2 clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X_train)
```

It gives me this:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Including Injection Of
> Non-RadioactiveDye (In Addition To Primary Lymphadenectomy)'  However,
> this row name was converted to a "2"...

Any help in slow, easy English is truly appreciated :)

Comment: How are you creating your `X_train`?

Comment: Hi There, this is my X_train: X = cases.iloc[:, [6, 10]].values
y = cases.iloc[:, [7, 11]].values and this is  my splitting of the data: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = (
train_test_split( 
    X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state=0))

Answer (score 0):

So after much searching, in order to convert string data to float or numerical, this is the code that worked for the above problem:
#Creating a label encoding for Ter Pro Nam to apply numerical values

```
labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
labelEncoder.fit(cases['TerProNam'])
cases['TerProNam'] = labelEncoder.transform(cases['TerProNam'])
```

You do have to import:
import mglearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

Hope this helps someone!!